# Agregar un item no existente a un JSON desde js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

He intentado con:

```
var data = {};
var file = {file:{name: 'Getter - Blood.mp3', path: '/user1'}};
data.push(file);
//Y tambien asi
data.file = file;
```

Pero nada funciona no tira error ni nada pero luego al imprimirlo en pantalla no aparecen los nuevos items

Comment: `push` no debería funcionar porque `data` no es un arreglo. El segundo debería funcionar sin problemas. Asegúrate de no tener la línea `data.push` sin comentar, de lo contrario `data.file = file` no podrá ejecutarse.

Comment: ¿Si el json viene de un callback es lo mismo?

Comment: No habría problemas. Asegúrate que tu objeto no es una cadena de texto JSON sino un objeto JavaScript propio.

Comment: Dice "object" con la funcion typeof()

Comment: Entonces dale, con confianza.

Comment: fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
   files.forEach(function(file) {
    if(fs.statSync(dir + '/' + file).isFile()){
     data.files = file;
    }else{
     data.dirs = {file};
    }
    
   });
  });
  console.log(data);

Comment: Me parece que tu problema va por otro lado. Si quieres todos los archivos que cumplan con ciertas validaciones, mejor utiliza `Array#filter` en lugar de `Array#forEach`.

Comment: Luego veré eso, ahora quiero agregarlos solamente pero no se puede.

Comment: Me refiero a que con eso obtendrás solo un arreglo y luego puedes agregar ese arreglo resultado de filtrar tus datos en lugar de hacer lo que quieres, que me parece más como forzar a JavaScript a que haga algo. Es como si mataras una mosca con un mata moscas o con una mesa: puedes lograrlo con la mesa pero ese no es su propósito.

Comment: La función fs.readdir es async entonces primero hacia el console.log() y luego hacia eso (después de leer todo el directorio)

Answer (score 5):

### solución con array

Si tu intención es tener varios registros tipo "file" (de tu ejemplo) puedes empezar con un array

```
var data = [];
var file = {name: 'Getter - Blood.mp3', path: '/user1'};
data.push(file);
console.log(data);
// se muestra: 
// [ { name: 'Getter - Blood.mp3', path: '/user1' } ]
data.push({name: "Other.mp3", path: undefined});
console.log(data);
// se muestra:
// [ { name: 'Getter - Blood.mp3', path: '/user1' },
//  { name: 'Other.mp3', path: undefined } ]
```

### solución con object

```
var data = {};
var file = {name: 'Getter - Blood.mp3', path: '/user1'};
data.file1 = file;
console.log(data);
// se muestra: 
// { file1: { name: 'Getter - Blood.mp3', path: '/user1' } }
data.file2 = {name: "Other.mp3", path: undefined});
console.log(data);
// se muestra:
// { file1: { name: 'Getter - Blood.mp3', path: '/user1' },
//   file2: { name: 'Other.mp3', path: undefined } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes

```
fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
    files.forEach(function(file) {
        if(fs.statSync(dir + '/' + file).isFile()){
            data.files = file; 
        }else{
            data.dirs = {file};
        }
    });
});
console.log(data);
res.render('algo', data);
```

Después

```
//Lee todo de una carpeta sean archivos o directorios
fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
    //Para por cada uno. 
    files.forEach(function(file) {
        console.log(file);
        //Pregunta: ¿Eres un archivo?
        if(fs.statSync(dir + '/' + file).isFile()){
            //Aqui si los es, entonces lo agrega a la variable archivos
            data['files'] = file; 
        }else{
             //Aqui NO los es, entonces lo agrega a la variable directorios
             data['dirs'] = file; 
        } 
    });
    //Lo envia
    res.render("algo", data);
    //Imprime todos los datos
    console.log(data);
});
```

Tambien se puede con fs.readdirSync()

```
var files = fs.readdirSync(_dir);
//lo mismo excepto por el callback
```

Comment: Si puedes agregar alguna explicación de tu codigo estaría bien.